# Apply custom css to sapui5 tile

Tags: javascript, css, sapui5

I have created dynamic tiles for my SAPUI5 application, the tiles on this page need to be resized so I added a custom css style class.

```
.administrationTile {
    width: 18rem;
    height: 14rem;
}
```

Which I apply like this:

```
oTile.addStyleClass('administrationTile');
```

My problem is that this only adjusts the size of the tile itself, but doesn't change the size of the content in the tile. I previously did it like this in the onAfterRendering part:

```
setTimeout(function(){

for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++)
{
     $("#MyTileContainer-"+i+".sapMTile").css({
       width: "18rem",
       height: "14rem"    
     });
}

$("div.sapMTileContent").css({
    width: "18rem",
    height: "14rem"
});

$("div.sapMStdTileNumDiv").css("width", "12rem");

}, 200);
```

Which does work, but it's a very ugly method because it doesn't work at all times and you see the tile changing in size (without timeout it doesn't even work at all)

My question is how can I apply the other classes (sapMTileContent and sapMStdTileNumDiv) that belong to this tile without this ugly workaround.

Answer (score 0):

> this only adjusts the size of the tile itself, but doesn't change the size of the content in the tile.

As far as I understand, you are modifying the tile width, but not the contents.

```
.administrationTile {
    width: 18rem;
    height: 14rem;
    font-size: 4rem; /*  <---  */
}
```

Look at it in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rx2Lmhr9/1/)

Comment: This does change the size of the font inside the tile, but this doesn't change the size of the content inside the tile, that is what I want to achieve, I need to specifically change the "sapMTileContent" and "sapMStdTileNumDiv" classes to make it align correctly with the size. 

http://imgur.com/a/rVdmX

Here is an example, the first one is how it shows now, the second one is how it should be (in the second one I added the last 3 lines of the workaround)

Comment: Then look for the piece of code that is cropping the the text to 20 char max. - It is not about the CSS, it is about the code that is writing that HTML. -

Comment: Well, that is defined by the size of the content of the tile, so If I make it larger with css it allows me to input more text as show'n on the screenshot, so I don't think that is the fix. Also there is nothing to find about cropping.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered this may be a CSS inheritance issue. If you inspect the object and focus on the object you are trying to influence and then look at the CSS styles that are being applied onto this object using Chrome's "Inspect element" right-click option you may want to check if the style is not being over-ridden later in the CSS chain.
(Hope this makes sense?)